# PHP: Exiting a function

Tags: php, function

A newbie style question, I'm afraid. I was wondering if someone might tell me what best practice is in the following situation.

Should it be...

```
function submitted_data()
{
 //Testing user data
 if(userdata != correctlyentered)
 {
   display_form(errors);
 }
 //Submit verified data to server
}
```

In which case, what's the correct syntax when calling `display_form` from within `submitted_data`, because at the moment it continues to submit the data to the server when I don't want it to.

Or should it be...

```
function submitted_data()
{
 //Testing user data
 if(userdata != correctlyentered)
 {
   display_form(errors);
 }
 else
 {
 //Submit verified data to server
 }
}
```

Or does it not make any difference?

Thanks.

Comment: is it me or are those two code samples exactly the same?

Comment: i think this need more explanation - what is "Submit data to server"? this is php, this should already _be_ on the server.

Comment: They're not the same, no. I've just simplified the question, though, so maybe that will help. Thanks.

Comment: @oezi, It's a remote server done via an API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second example is valid:

```
function submitted_data();
{
 //Testing user data
 if(userdata != correctlyentered)
 {
   display_form(errors);
 }
 else
 {
 //Submit verified data to server
 }
}
```

To "exit" a function, use `return`. It could have been done like this:

```
function submitted_data();
{
 //Testing user data
 if(userdata != correctlyentered)
 {
   display_form(errors);
   return;
 }
 //Submit verified data to server
}
```

Comment: +1 Excellent. Thanks for the straightforward answer. It seems to me that the "else" version would be more efficient than the "return" version(?). Either way, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Django: They're probably very similar. I prefer using `return` in error handling because it makes it clear that `if false: don't continue`. In short, you shouldn't worry about performance, but readability here (although both methods are readable, so it's a matter of personal preference).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use the else statement and don't write a return statement inside the if, the first example will submit data to the server in every case.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get out of a function, you need to `return`.

Usually, if you're getting out of a function because you detected a problem - you'll `return false` so you can code around what happens if the function sends you back a 0/false result.

If your function works as you'd like, use `return true` so you can code around what to do when the function did what it was supposed to with no problems.

Of course you can return other things - personally I try to avoid using 'echo' in functions so that I can choose to either keep or output the data in different situations.

So:

```
function myFunction() {
  $result = "something happened";
  return $result;
}

echo myFunction();
```

Would be preferable to:

```
function myFunction() {
  $result = "something happened";
  echo $result;
  return true;
}
```

Because I can call myFunction just to test it without having to display the results, or I can choose to display the results.  Two birds killed, one stone used.

Answer (score 0):

First off, do not put semicolons after the function declarations.

Anyway, this depends entirely on what you're trying to do.  If you add the else (2nd block), the code will only run if `userdata != correctlyentered` is FALSE.  If you don't add the else (1st block), the code will always run.

Edit:
To exit a function, you can use `return`.

```
if(userdata != correctlyentered)
{
  display_form(errors);
  return;
}
```

Comment: Oops. It's only pseudo code, but yeah, I removed the semi-colons.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case you should choose the variant with the least code nesting inside {}

```
function submitted_data()
{
 //Testing user data
 if(userdata != correctlyentered)
 {
   display_form(errors);
   return;
 }

 //Submit verified data to server

}
```